# While loop is not working in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

The program will allow me to input the values, but their is no calculations and it doesn't print. I have moved the endProgram input all over and it just turns it into an infinite loop.

```
def main ():
 endProgram = "no"
 while endProgram == "no":
        totalBottles = getBottles()
        totalPayout = calcPayout(totalBottles)
        printInfo = (totalBottles, totalPayout)
        endProgram = raw_input("Do you want to end the program? Enter yes or no:") 

def getBottles():
    counter = 1
    totalBottles = 0
    todayBottles = 0

    while counter <= 7:
        todayBottles = input("Enter number of bottles for today:")
        totalBottles = totalBottles + todayBottles
        counter = counter + 1
    return totalBottles

def calcPayout(totalBottles):
    totalPayout = 0
    totalPayout = totalBottles * .10
    return totalPayout
def printInfo(totalBottles,totalPayout):
    print "The total bottles collected is:",totalBottles
    print "The total payout is $ :",totalPayout
```

Comment: Do you call `main()` somewhere? As stands, this code will exit without doing anything.

Comment: Yes main() is at the end. I guess it didn't get picked up on the copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print you have to remove `=` in line (because it assigns values to variable)

```
 printInfo = (totalBottles, totalPayout)
```

It has to be:

```
 printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout)
```

This way you call function with variables.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple oversight. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a [tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) (totalBottles, totalPayout) to a function, that is the reason why is not working.

`printInfo` is a function **that only prints** and has no returns... therefore change the statement

```
printInfo = (totalBottles, totalPayout)
```

for `printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout)`